# Чем заменить trigger в ie

Tags: jquery, javascript, internet-explorer

Есть у меня триггеры для кнопки submit при выборе файла пользователем с компьютера. Однако сегодня узнал, что ie9 не разрешает использовать trigger на submit. Можно это как-то обойти? Или обязательно делать кнопку "Отправить"?

```
<form action="upserver.php" id="upfiles" method="POST" target="uploadresult" name="upfiles" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display: none;">
    <div id="filewrapper">

        Выбрать файл
        <input name="file[]" type="file" size="30" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" />

    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="true">Отправить</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#comp').click(function() {
                $('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
              })

            $('input[type=file]').change(function() {
                $('#send').trigger('click');
            })
        })
    </script>

</form>
```

Comment: Код покажите нерабочий-то.

Comment: Я использую .click(). Везде работает. Вы наверно просто скрываете type="file" через display: none, вот и Ваша ошибка.

Comment: Дело не в этом. Триггер имитирует событие, т.е. как будто вы нажали на элемент. А click это прямой вызов события.

Comment: Видите ли, в IE это по умолчанию запрещено в целях безопасности. Нельзя программно вызвать submit файла. Вопрос в том КАК ЭТО ОБОЙТИ? Естественно, не катит просто поменять локально настройки IE, по понятным причинам. Нужно программное решение. Как сымитировать Submit программно в IE.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо имитации нажатия на submit, можно попробовать напрямую саму форму отправить:

```
$('#upfiles').submit();
```

Проблем с этим вариантом в IE не замечал, единственное, не тестировал на формах с файлами.

Comment: Нет, с формой не выходит. Пробовал.

Comment: Протестировал в IE9 + IE10, все работает. http://jsfiddle.net/g9cvn/1/

Comment: Событие происходит, но файл он не пропускает. jsFiddle не даёт полной картины.

Comment: Еще один тест, загружает файл, затем отображает имя, тип и размер.: http://almanac.pro/test